# Why do widgets disappear after running out of battery?

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, launcher, app-widgets, trebuchet

After phone shutting down by running out of battery, when I start it again all the widgets disappear. At first I thought that this is a problem of my launcher (Apex), but even the native one (Trebuchet) lose all the widgets. They won't disappear if I shut down or reboot the phone as usual. Why is that?

Phone information:

- **OS**: CyanogenMod 11
- **Model**: Samsung GT-I9195
- **Launchers**: Apex (free) and Trebuchet

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing apps on your SD card? If so this is the main reason for this to happen. Apps having widget functionalities should be installed in phone storage . Some app even give you a small pop up saying

`Widgets Functionalities might not work if you install this app in you external storage`.

Hope This helped.

Comment: I forgot to add. No, I don't.

Comment: same here... I usually turn off the phone over night and when I power it back on the widgets are gone